# Overriding max_value in django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I use a `ModelForm` and I want to set a max_value for an `IntegerField` without losing the other attributes which where created from the model (verbose_name, etc.).

This is my ModelForm:

```
class DataForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start_range_points'].max_value = 1000
    class Meta():
        model = DataModel
```

This doesn't work, django does not apply the validation for large numbers. If I create the field in the following way the validation works but I lose the information which was created from the Model.

```
class DataForm(ModelForm):
    start_range_points = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=1000)
    class Meta():
        model = DataModel
```

What can I do to achieve something similar to attempt #1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The validator for max_value is added in IntegerField's `__init__` function if max_value is present. So you will need to manually add the validator, something like:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
class DataForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        validators = [ v for v in self.fields['start_range_points'].validators if not isinstance(v, MaxValueValidator) ]
        validators.append( MaxValueValidator(1000) )
        self.fields['start_range_points'].validators = validators

    class Meta():
        model = DataModel
```